# Spring Autowiring Beans giving Class Cast Exception

Tags: java, spring

Here is my class

```
@Configuration
class MongoDBConfig {
    private Logger logger = LoggingFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    @Bean
    @Scope(value = "singleton", proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES)
    public MongoClient mongoClient() throws UnknownHostException {
        logger.error("In Dev mode:");
        return new MongoClient("fctest");

    }

    @Bean
    public DB mongoDB() throws UnknownHostException{
        try {
            return mongoClient().getDB(FCProperties.MONGO_DB_NAME);
        }catch (UnknownHostException ue){
            logger.error("Error occurred: "+ue.getMessage());
            throw ue;
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how I'm using it -

```
public class UserRepository extends BaseRepository {
    @Autowired
    public UserRepository(DB mongoDB) {
        super("users", mongoDB);
    }
}
```

I'm getting the following error

> Error creating bean with name 'mongoDB' defined in class path resource [com/fctest/mongo/config/MongoDBConfig.class]: Instantiation of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Factory method [public com.mongodb.DB com.fctest.mongo.config.MongoDBConfig.mongoDB() throws java.net.UnknownHostException] threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.proxy.$Proxy13 cannot be cast to com.mongodb.MongoClient

Comment: Why do you use `proxyMode = ScopedProxyMode.INTERFACES`? Does the error happen without this, too?

Comment: Try using `ScopedProxyMode.TARGET_CLASS`.

Comment: Changing to TARGET_CLASS worked. Thanks.